# Merge all content control from multiple files into one

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I am working on vba project. The requirement is to merge multiple word document content into one single word document. It is to be done by ContentControl tags. I have already created two word document having unique content control tag id. Now I need to build logic for merging their content into one.

```
  Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName)

  With WordApp.ActiveDocument
          For i = 1 To .ContentControls.Count
                Select Case .ContentControls(i).Tag
                    Case "cc1": strEnding = "st"  -- word content including format and style
                    Case "cc2": strEnding = "nd"
                    Case "cc3": strEnding = "rd"
                    Case Else: strEnding = "th"
                End Select
          Next
        End With
```

Now I want to merge all data (including format and style also if there is a table) into one single document.

Please suggest me how could i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Foo()
Dim i As Long
Dim MyName As String, MyPath As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Documents.Add

MyPath = "C:\your_path_here\" ' <= change this as necessary

MyName = Dir$(MyPath & "*.doc") ' not *.* if you just want doc files

Do While MyName <> ""
If InStr(MyName, "~") = 0 Then
Selection.InsertFile _
FileName:="""" & MyPath & MyName & """", _
ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, _
Attachment:=False
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
End If

MyName = Dir ' gets the next doc file in the directory
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In a general way it should work using Range.FormattedText for both sides of the equation. Get the target Range in the one document and assign the FormattedText of an individual content control's Range to it.